# Rails: Adding polymorphic associations between three models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration, associations

I have three models : User, Agency and Client.
Currently,

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :agency
  has_one :client 
end

class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :users
end

class Agency < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :users
end
```

I want to change associations and create a polymorphic association such as this:

```
User belongs_to :role , :polymorphic => true
```

and

```
Client has_one :user, as: :role
Agency has_one :user, as: :role
```

I am a novice rails developer. How can I achieve this? HOw to write a migration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add two fields, `role_id` and `role_type` in user model. You can create new migration as follows

```
rails g migration addNewFieldsToUsers role_id:integer role_type:string
```

After running `rake db:migrate` you need to modify the associations as follows

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :role, polymorphic: true          
end

class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :user, as: :role, class_name: 'User'  
end

class Agency < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :user, as: :role, class_name: 'User'
end
```

Now restart the rails server.

Answer (score 0):

A migration is not needed. There are no associations between models in the database (which is what a migration would change).

What you need to do is change the models `app/models/user.rb` and `app/models/location.rb`. simply remove the `belongs_to:` from user and add it in loction: `belongs_to: user`.

Comment: Actually i have edited my question.. can u answer this? Sorry for not asking proper question earlier.